# GLSL C++ Only first sampler array index is accessible

Tags: opengl, c++

I have the following shader, which whose fragment shader contains a sampler array of 16 elements.

**Fragment**

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 _uv;
flat in int _instanceID;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D sampler[16];

void main() {
    color = texture(sampler[_instanceID], _uv);
}
```

Now when I try to set the second array element using the following method

```
void Shader::setUniform(const std::string& uniform, GLuint* values, size_t amount) const {
    bindProgram();

    GLuint loc = getUniformLocation(uniform + "[0]");
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        glUniform1ui(loc+i, values[i]);
        std::cout << values[i] << " "; //For debug
    }
    std::cout << std::endl; //For debug
}
```

It just sets the first element of the shader. Even though I'm passing 2 values.

**This is the output of the cout's:**

```
5 4
5 4
5 4
5 4
...
```

Looking up the shader variables with GDebugger, only the first element is set.
[image]
It also only draws the first (index 0) image.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using uniform sampler2DArray in your GLSL and GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY in your C++?  You have #version 330 core so these are supported, and they're probably what you actually want to use instead of an array of samplers.

Answer (score 1):

`getUniformLocation` isn't required to be continuous for array uniforms, so instead of just fetching the location of `"sampler[0]"`, you also need to find the location for `"sampler[1]"` and so on.

Comment: That is the problem, if I try to get the uniform location of "sampler[1]", it does not find it. Only for "sampler[0]"!

Comment: That was not apparent from the code you posted, please update the code sample if that is not the code you are using.